# SQL Insert newest value from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, max

I have two PostgreSQL tables and I want to insert the most recent value from a column in one table into the other.  I've tried something like this but I can't get it to work:

```
 INSERT INTO inland (lt_dispatch_level)
 SELECT named_lt_dispatch_level
 FROM obs
 WHERE created_at = (
 SELECT MAX(created_at) 
 FROM obs)
```

I need my  inland.lt_dispatch_level = the most recent value from obs.named_lt_dispatch_level.
Is there a way to select only that value?

Comment: what `error` your getting ?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just not the desired result.  My query above returns a new row of data,  whereas I want to populate an empty cell in an existing row.  I want my inland.lt_dispatch_level column in row 1 to equal the most recent row's value of my obs.named_lt_dispatch_level.  I also want this value to change everytime a new record appears in my obs table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you made it clear that you are trying to update a column in another, you need to utilize an update statement, not an insert. I went ahead and edited the answer.

Try This:

```
UPDATE inland SET lt_dispatch_level = obs.named_lt_dispatch_level 
FROM obs WHERE obs.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) 
FROM obs) AND inland.cartodb_id = 1
```

The query should return you with the latest row.

Comment: This query works the same as mine above only it is written more efficiently, returning an entire new row from obs into my inland table.  I only want the newest value from my obs.named_lt_dispatch_level to populate inland.lt_dispatch_level in row 1.

Comment: Assuming that named_lt_dispatch_level is of type timestamp, then your insert query should work, however, if it is formatted different, you may have more than one row with the same created_at value as to the max created_at. In that case you will be inserting multiple rows with row that equal to the max.  Since you made it clear that you want to update a column from one table to another, I went ahead and modified the answer. Please edit your question and avoid using the word insert when you want to update a column.

Comment: Will this query apply automatically each time my obs table gets a newer record?

Comment: You will need to create a trigger on table obs which will fire after an insert is made on your table in order to automatically update your other tabel. You can get more info on triggers here. [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: when I run your query I get this error: "aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE".  I will look into the trigger, that sounds promising.

Comment: I meant to use your select subquery. Fixed.

Comment: Ran it and now it says that inland.row does not exist.  I am working on this PostgreSQL table in CartoDB and maybe it does not support the row feature.

Comment: row is suppose to be the name of your primary key you use to specify which row you want to select. I just use row as a example. Which i think it a bad idea since row is a reserve word. ... inland.(whatever column name is your primary key) = 1

Comment: Would chat but only have 1 rep, i ran your query on my primary key of cartodb_id and got this error: "column "inland" of relation "inland" does not exist".  My query loks like this:             UPDATE inland SET inland.lt_dispatch_level = obs.named_lt_dispatch_level 
FROM obs
WHERE obs.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) 
FROM obs) AND inland.cartodb_id = 1

Comment: remove the inland from the set inland.lt_dispatch_level. It should be ...set lt_dispatch_level = .... sorry about that. i'm editing this through my phone. :/

Comment: That worked thank you! That was exactly what I needed! Now I will have to see if I can setup a trigger that will run that query as a function.  I'll edit that answer and mark it for you since your on your phone.